# JSDoc: Annotating an exported method

Tags: javascript, annotations, documentation-generation, jsdoc

If I define an object like this:

```
/**
 * My Cool Object
 * @constructor
 */

 function MyCoolObject() {

       /**
        * Cool Method, private
        * @param {!string} parameter
        */

       function localMethod(parameter) {
           // do stuff
       }

       // Export the method
       this.exportedMethod = localMethod;

 }
```

I'd like to know, if at all possible, how to tell **JSDOC** to use the annotation for `localMethod` in `exportedMethod`, or how can I annotate `exportedMethod`, because if I do:

```
       // Export the method

       /**
        * Cool Method 
        * @param {!string} parameter
        */
       this.exportedMethod = localMethod;
```

**JSDOC** assumes it's a field rather than a method, then only uses the description, ignoring the `@param` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reduce it to:

```
/**
 * My Cool Object
 * @constructor
 */

function MyCoolObject()  {
    /**
     * Cool Method, private
     * @param {!string} parameter
     */
    this.exportedMethod = function (parameter) {
        // do stuff
    };

}
```

You can do `var localMethod = this.exportedMethod` right after if you want a local reference to the method. In the off chance that you've over-simplified your example and you *need* to first assign to `localMethod` before assigning to `this.exportedMethod` you could do this:

```
/**
 * My Cool Object
 * @constructor
 */

function MyCoolObject()  {

    function localMethod(parameter) {
        // do stuff
    }

    /**
     * Cool Method, private
     * @param {!string} parameter
     * @function
     */
    // Export the method
    this.exportedMethod = localMethod;

}
```

The `@function` declaration tells jsdoc that it is dealing with a function.

Comment: The second thing is what I'm looking for! I don't want to reduce it like in your first solution because those local methods are also called locally inside the object closure, and I prefer to keep them private so they are obfuscated, etc..